# i want to iterate completely inside a loop which is defined inside a function in python(by calling once in python)

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

```
 def call():
   num=1
   if(num<=9):
     print(num)
     num=num+1
   else:
     print("bye")

 call()
```

**my output**
1

my loop is not iterating completely inside a loop  it is calling once and exiting
**wanted output**
1
1
1
1
1(like these till the end of loop)

2) I know i can do it with for loop but i want to do it with generators

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a generate function.

```
 def call():
   num=1
   while (num<=9):
     yield 1
     num=num+1
   yield "bye"

 for i in call():
   print(i)
```

Comment: generally i want if and else to be run in some other code just i want to make sure can if and else be iterated in a function

Comment: Yes, if and else can be inside a function.  Are you asking me how would I take 1 as input to a loop or what?

Comment: yes taking 1 as input and to a loop   (the main reason is i am having conditional statements  inside a if and else and i want  to iter if the condition is true)

Comment: if you give me permission i will share my code in bit bucket with you

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh Sure, go for it.  I'm happy to look, but I don't have an account is it required?  Send me a link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527517/i-want-to-write-the-complete-code-in-one-function-but-it-is-only-iterating-once    this is my code just give some modifications